How to crawl data using Selenium and split cell values in Google Sheets
 
Currently, I am retrieving all the <td> values and saving them to Google Sheets

For the page to be crawled, the date and rank are located as td > div > div > span, b

So, when I extract only the <td> elements, all the data gets stored in a single cell. Is there a way to store it as follows?
For example:

A2: 11-27(Wed), a3:291st
B2: 11-26(Tue), b3:278th
(...)

split and bs4 are not working

Please include your code in the post as formatted, copy-pastable text rather than screenshot. Posting code/command/error screenshots is discouraged. Also a valid link to your data (or a subset of it, or a made-up toy example) would be a step toward including a minimal reproducible example in your post, which is indeed very much needed to get valuable help.
